# How to copy file from git to remote docker container in jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins

How to copy a file from git to remote docker container in jenkins? i know how to copy to local docker container where jenkins is installed (on the same server).

I wrote my Git repo in SourceCodeManagement. I want to execute cmd over ssh. My parameters in jenkins below.

How to write 2nd command to copy a file? Jenkins gives me error there is no /remote/index.html

[image]

Comment: Have you read [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) in the Jenkins documentation?  That can run build steps `docker.inside { ... }` a container without manually copying things.

Comment: No, but i' ve read it now, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like your are not going forward in good approach.
First ensure your docker container running  or run it manually not in exec command.

not in ssh publisher in jenkins

```
docker run --name nginx -d -p 80:80 nginx
```

then you can run any command like

```
docker exec -ti my_container sh -c "echo a && echo b"

docker exec -it <container_id_or_name> sh -c  " git clone url"
```

You should copy any file in docker container rather than you should mount host volume with container volume by this way.

```
docker run \
  --rm \
  -u root \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v "$HOME":/home \
  jenkinsci/blueocean
```

Comment: ok, i will improve it according ur advice, but how to copy from git to remote docker container through jenkins ? docker cp?

Comment: if your container is running then you can write  sh script in your pipeline where you can write the command of copying your file either using docker cp  (if you clone that repo in local machine) or docker exec -it <container_id_or_name> sh -c  " git clone url"  and run your pipeline.Be please informed that first add your docker node as jenkins node to have the privilege of running pipeline script.

Comment: can i copy file to docker without cloning a repo to local machine?

Comment: I think its not possible, you want to copy one file from your remote(online) git repo to docker container.

Comment: But you can download that the single file from the remote git repo. Please follow
"If it’s just a single file, you can go to your GitHub repo, find the file in question, click on it, and then click “View Raw”  data, Copy the link and try to download by this way (docker exec -it <container_id_or_name> sh -c  " curl  -O copied name or wget copied name")

Comment: if i use docker & jenkins on the same server, i can use command: "docker cp index.html container_name". So if i use use docker & jenkins on different servers, i can't use this command.

Comment: yes, docker cp is only  to  copy from the container’s file system to the local machine or the reverse, from the local filesystem to the container.

Comment: if i want to use cmd "docker exec -it <container_id_or_name> sh -c  " git clone url"" i must install git in container, yes?